# Rails: Users can visit edit view urls of other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users can edit their profile at `mydomain.com/users/3/edit`.  But they can also visit `mydomain.com/users/7/edit` (or any other ID).

It doesn't actually affect the data at all, since I'm just using current_user but I'd like to change the path to mydomain.com/profile/edit. Currently just using:

```
  resources :users
```

How would I alter this? Is it as simple as just adding below line, or is there a cleaner way of doing it?

```
get 'profile/edit', to: 'users#edit'
```

Comment: Your revised route is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, what about to block 3rd party users to edit ?

In users_controller.rb

`before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]`

```
private
def correct_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user == @user
end
```